# differentiating the generating function of the Legendre equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, generating-functions, legendre-polynomials

I need to differentiate the generating function

$$G(x,t)=\sum a_n(x)t^n$$ w.r.t. x in order to solve

$$\tfrac{d}{dx}[(1-x^2)\tfrac{dG}{dx}]+\tfrac{d}{dt}[t^2\tfrac{dG}{dt}]$$.

But I don't understand how this can be done ..... any suggestions ?

context:I know that not giving an attempt is frowned upon in this community. I almost always do. In this particular instance this is part of a much larger question which I have in fact given a big attempt at but it is too long to type out. I do'nt want the question done for me I just want to know how to differentiate G wrt x

Note: these were supposed to be partial derivatives ( i didn't know the symbol)

Note : $G(x,t)=(1-2xt+t^2)^{-1/2}$

Comment: [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) links to advice about asking questions, and about getting yourself unstuck.

Comment: @DevashishKaushik I know that not giving an attempt is frowned upon in this community. I almost always do. In this particular instance this is part of a much larger question which I have in fact given a big attempt at but it is too long to type out. I do'nt want the question done for me I just want to know how to differentiate G wrt x

Comment: Well, maybe you should add that to the question (as context) :).

Comment: Also, I think you need to clarify whether you are looking for partial or total derivatives. In case you explicitly need $\frac{d}{dx}$, then you are looking for the latter. You can easily Google how to do that.

Comment: In case you are not sure which one to use, you should provide more context so others can figure out which one is applicable, imho.

Comment: You can use   `\partial`   for partial derivatives $\partial$. See the [MathJax quick guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While taking partial derivatives, you treat the other variable as if it were a constant :

$\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{x}} = \frac{\partial{{(1 - 2xt + t^2)}^{-1/2}}}{\partial{x}}$

$= {-1 \over 2}\cdot{(1-2xt + t^2)}^{-3/2}\cdot \frac{\partial{(1-2xt+t^2)}}{\partial{x}}$ (Using the chain rule)

$= {-1 \over 2}\cdot{(1-2xt + t^2)}^{-3/2}\cdot(-2)$

$= {(1-2xt + t^2)}^{-3/2}$

---

## UPDATE -

For the series version, simply use the same procedure (all variables except $x$ are to be treated as constants , mentally replace variable $t$ by constant $a$; $x \mapsto t$ ). Here you will get something along the lines of :

$\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}} { \{ \Sigma (a_n(x) \cdot (t)^n) \} } = \Sigma \{ \frac{\partial{ (a_n(x) \cdot (t)^n) }}{\partial{x}} \}$

$= \Sigma \{ (t)^n \cdot \frac{\partial{a_n(x)}}{\partial{x}} \}$

---

However, **I do *not* think that is what you should be looking for**.

What you need is :

$$  \frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{x}} = \frac{1}{{(1-2xt + t^2)}^{3/2}}$$

and

$$ \frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{t}} = \frac{(x-t)}{{(1-2xt + t^2)}^{3/2}} $$

Be sure to accept if that solves your problem ;) (@exodius)

Comment: I think I have to use the series version of G though. cos the next part of the question say show that a_n satisfies the legendre eq and that indeed a_n=p_n

Comment: I think what I need to do is find an equation for A_n then put this equation into the legendre eq to show that it is satisfied